# error when displaying contents in a file c++

Tags: c++, arrays, file, structure

I am trying to read in data from a file, and then store it into an array of structures. Database needs to be displayed while reading from file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct student 
{
    string LastName;
    string FirstName;
    int MemberID;
    int TelephoneNum;
};

int main() 
{
    student Student1;
    int count = 0;   // counter of student

    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("library_database.txt");
    if (!fin.is_open() ) 
    { 
        cerr << "File <library_database.txt> not found";  
        cin.get();  
        return 1; 
    };

    // creating array of students
    student * Students = new student[count];

    // reading student data from file
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) 
    {
        cin >> Students[i].LastName >> Students[i].FirstName >> 
        Students[i].MemberID >> Students[i].TelephoneNum;
    }

    fin.close();

    // display full list of students
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        cout << i + 1 << ". " << Students[i].LastName << " " << Students[i].FirstName << " "
        << Students[i].MemberID << " " << Students[i].TelephoneNum<< endl;
    }
}
```

When I run the program I get
1. 0 0 
2. 0 0 
and so on to 100.

Comment: If this is your real code, you see that `count=0` and never changes?

Comment: what is the error? What is the input? What is the behavior you expect vs the behavior you get?

Comment: Definite invalid reads in your second `for`.  Also, seems odd you're using `fin` but reading from `std::cin`.

Comment: use vector for Students datas. you can easily manage the Students list.